# Rename Oracle logs with the current date

Tags: shell, logs, logrotate

I would like to rename my Oracle alert logs with the current date and compress them after X days. Could this be done with a shell script? Also I must not use logrotate

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SE is not a script-writing service.  Also, too broad.

Comment: Oracle 12c on CentOS 7

Comment: [logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate).  available pre-packaged for most, if not all, linux distros.  including centos.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ - See for instance http://www.dadbm.com/oracle-database-housekeeping-methods-unix-log-rotation/

Answer (score 0):

I googled centOS log rotate and the first link was how to set it up.

For you specific need, set up the oracle logrotate script in `/etc/logrotate.d` if it doesn't already exist and add 
`dateext`
`dateformat %Y-%m-%d.` to your oracle log rotate file.  Directions for setting up a log rotate on Red hat / CentOS - https://linuxconfig.org/setting-up-logrotate-on-redhat-linux  You may need to set up a specific cron job to do it on a time interval other than daily, weekly or monthly.  Alternatively you can rotate the log based on space as well.

Comment: I know how to setup logrotate, but I need to do it with a script